# lock и try-catch

Tags: c#

Как правильно написать когда операция требует одновременно и то и другое?

```
try
{
    lock(locker)
    {
         ....
    }
}
catch(...)
{
     ...
}
```

или так

```
lock(locker)
{
    try
    {
         ...
    }
    catch(...)
    {
      ...
    }
 }
```

И как быть в случае возникновения исключения, если оно будет залочено?

Comment: и так, и так можно. "исключения ... будет залочено" - это как?

Comment: @Igor то есть если в операции возникла ошибка, то ведь как-то нужно будет снять лок, он же из-за ошибки останется активным, как я понимаю.

Comment: @Bulson с чего бы?

Comment: Почитайте в любом учебнике что конструкция lock делает...

Comment: Нет, не останется. `lock` - это сокращенная запись `Monitor.Enter/Exit` с `try-finaly`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: @Igor ОК, я понял, спасибо.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

На *SO* **настоятельно не рекомендуют использовать вместе c** `lock` **конструкцию** `try-catch`. А советуют поступать так:

```
lock(whatever)
{
    try
    {
        MakeAMess();
    }
    finally
    {
      CleanItUp();
      // Либо доводим операцию до конца, либо откатываем в прежнее состояние
    }
}
```

Там пишут, что выбрасывание исключения в `lock` нарушает саму суть ради чего существует этот самый `lock`. Поэтому если возникло исключение есть два варианта:

1. Прибить процесс совсем с помощью [`Environment.FailFast()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx)
2. Либо, если это возможно, откатить в прежнее состояние, до `lock`.

В оригинале можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997360/locking-a-resource-via-lock-within-try-is-it-wrong).